# Platform conditionals in docker-compose

Tags: macos, docker, networking, docker-compose

I have this weird statement that I have to paste into my `docker-compose` file to make things work but only because I use macOS:

```
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1450
```

Is there a way to leave this in but make this set of statements conditional on the host platform?

Comment: odd is that only Mac is affected due to mtu, are you sure you have network interface configured well? or are you using vpn that is not sending proper mtu configuration?

Comment: I have no idea and this whole Docker networking is a dark art to me. I have instructions to paste this in but I thought it could be nice to just conditionally include it.